# Which files in a polymer app should be committed to the repository?

Tags: git, github, polymer

My app's directory structure is as given below:

[image: App includes elements folder , routes ,images etc]

The app folder includes an elements folder, routes, and scripts. Do I need to commit the whole `public` folder or should I leave out `node_modules` and `bower_components`?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you an always re-download bower- and node modules from their repositories, so you would not need to commit them.

I would however recommend checking-in everything you need to run your project, for these reasons:

- Not to be affected of modules being removed from an official repository
- Be able to build your project without needing to download possibly many modules from an official repository